# Rails - View Object Iteration Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

When I iterate an object in my view, it renders the objects itself too.

I have:

```
@portfolio_queued = Artist.where(:state => 'portfolio_queued')
```

And:

```
= for artist in @portfolio_queued
  %p
    = "#{artist.name}"
    %br
    = "#{artist.state}"
```

And it's rendering:

```
mauko
portfolio_queued

quiroga
portfolio_queued

quiroga
portfolio_queued
#<Artist:0x10652ca90>#<Artist:0x1065296b0>#<Artist:0x106529340>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so just repalcing

```
= for artist in @portfolio_queued
```

for

```
- for artist in @portfolio_queued
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just personal preference but I find that hard to read and would write it as

```
= @portfolio_queued.each do |artist| 
  %p
     artist.name 
     %br
     artist.status
```

Also, again personal preference - using paragraph tags for something that isn't a block of text is perceived as poor SEO/CSS; a span, div or table cell might be better.

Comment: when using "=" renders the output too, so i replaced it with "-"